# How bind property in model from json in asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a viewModel in Asp.net mvc5 that contains a object:

```
public class ConvenioViewModel
{
     public Convenio Convenio { get; set; }
     public string AnotherProperty {get;set;}
}
```

and I need that this property be populate with a json in Form Submit, because I populate this in input hidden with Json:

```
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Convenio, new { @id = "convenioJson" })
```

and my Javascript is this:

```
$('#convenioJson').val(JSON.stringify(data.List[i]));
```

My Json is this:

```
"{'Descricao':'UNIMED                   ','Id':1,'CodigoLogin':'bortolop','DataStamp':'/Date(903621226000)/'}"
```

but when I submit this form, my property "Convenio " is null.
what is the way to populate this in form submit? in ajax 
                                          I already know

Comment: yep, I´ll edit the question

Comment: `Convenio` is a complex object. You cannot bind a complex object to an input (look at the html your generating). You need an input for each property of the model. BUt what is the point of this - they can't be edited, so if you need the object in the POST method, then just get it again

Comment: ok, for each property in my object of viewmodel i need to bind like a input..I really understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because String type cannot parse to complex object. You should create custom databinder something like this:

```
public class ConvenioViewModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ConvenioViewModel viewModel = new ConvenioViewModel() {};

        string jsonConvenio = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("convenio").AttemptedValue;

        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        viewModel.Convenio = jss.Deserialize<Convenio>(jsonConvenio);

        return viewModel;
    }
}
```

In Application_Start() add

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(ConvenioViewModel), new ConvenioViewModelBinder());
```

That's all!